# Maven how to aggregate source from project depedencies

Tags: maven, osgi

I use maven-bundle-plugin to create osgi plugin from non osgi depedency and I want to include the source from this depedency into the projet build.

This is an example I create an OSGI bundle from jfreechart and when I publish it I want to include jfreechart sources.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.jfree.chart</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.netappsid.org.jfree.chart</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.13</version>
    <name>JFreeChart OSGI</name>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>


    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Export-Package>org.jfree.chart.*;org.jfree.data.*</Export-Package>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${pom.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Embed-Dependency>jfreechart;inline=true</Embed-Dependency>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>jfreechart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.13</version>
                    <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>*</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jfree</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.org.jfree</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.12</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>com.springsource.javax.servlet</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Comment: Are you using an IDE? When I run Maven against this POM, I get the expected JAR file which contains "META-INF\..." and "org\jfree\...". Since you have used "Embed-Dependency" as well, I'm guessing you also want the jfreechart JAR included, in which case remove the ";inline=true" statement and that will work.

Comment: this pom work but I want to add jfreechart source with maven-source-plugin into com.netappsid.org.jfree.chart-1.0.13-sources.jar when I will release it

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realise you wanted the actual source files. I've not seen jfreechart source files on any Maven repositories, but you can download them from their website directly and use: `<scope>system</scope>` and `<systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/jfree-sources.jar</systemPath>` for the dependency along with the maven-source-plugin.  I've not used it before though so wouldn't be any help with that. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. Here's what I ended up doing:

1. unpack the sources using the maven-dependency-plugin

   ```
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>unpack-sources</id>
         <goals>
           <goal>unpack</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/sources</outputDirectory>
           <artifactItems>
             <artifactItem>
               <groupId>commons-httpclient</groupId>
               <artifactId>commons-httpclient</artifactId>
               <version>3.1</version>
               <classifier>sources</classifier>
             </artifactItem>
           </artifactItems>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```
2. attach a sources artifact built with the maven-assembly-plugin

   ```
   <plugin>
     <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
     <executions>
       <execution>
         <id>source-assembly</id>
         <phase>package</phase>
         <goals>
           <goal>single</goal>
         </goals>
         <configuration>
           <descriptors>
             <descriptor>src.xml</descriptor>
           </descriptors>
         </configuration>
       </execution>
     </executions>
   </plugin>
   ```

   with the following descriptor (note that the descriptor id is used as the classifier ; the artifact is attached by default):

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <assembly xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly/1.1.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/assembly-1.1.0.xsd">
     <id>sources</id>
     <includeBaseDirectory>false</includeBaseDirectory>
     <formats>
       <format>jar</format>
     </formats>
     <fileSets>
       <fileSet>
         <directory>${project.build.directory}/sources</directory>
         <outputDirectory>/</outputDirectory>
         <useDefaultExcludes>true</useDefaultExcludes>
       </fileSet>
     </fileSets>
   </assembly>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly...

I've had to package many osgi-less JARs myself for use in an OSGi application. When using the `maven-bundle-plugin`, if you are using `Export-Package` in the manifest (or `osgi.bnd` file) then its classes will be included in the created bundle.

Example:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: ACME PostgreSQL Driver Bundle
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.acme.org.postgresql
Bundle-Version: 9.0.801.jdbc4

# NB: I've imported a little too much for what is required.
Import-Package: org.postgresql*;version="9.0-801.jdbc4", \
    javax*, \
    org.w3c.dom, \
    !org.ietf.jgss, \
    !org.dom.xml.views

Export-Package: org.postgresql*;version="9.0-801.jdbc4"

Private-Package: org.w3c.dom*, org.xml*, javax*
```

Here, the exported packages will be included in the JAR from my Maven dependencies in the POM.

If you also want to include the dependency JAR, then you can use `Embed-Dependency`:

```
Embed-Dependency: org.postgresql*;version="9.0-801.jdbc4"
Embed-Transitive: true
```

If this what you were looking for?

Tony

Comment: I already use the maven-bundle-plugin but when I release the project it doesn't include the source of <Embed-Dependency> instruction into myprojet-1.0.0-sources.jar

Comment: Are all of your other fields making it into your release bundle, i.e. Bundle-SymbolicName? Can you add this section of your POM to your question please so we can see it?